# Moment of measure for Dirac disintegration

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, moment-problem

Let $X,U,V$ be three subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^a,\mathbb{R}^b$ respectively and $\mu$  a probability measure supported on $X\times U\times V$.

The marginal $\mu_X$ of $\mu$ w.r.t $x$ is the Lebesgue measure:
$$
dx = d\mu_X(x) = \int_{U\times V} d\mu(x,u,v) \qquad (\star)
$$

We disintegrate $\mu$ as

$$
d \mu (x,u,v) = \Psi((u,v)\mid x) dx
$$

- Is the condition $(\star)$ is necessary to have such disintegration ?

I would like to force $\Psi((u,v)\mid x)$ to be as singular as possible, that is 
$$
\Psi((u,v)\mid x) = \delta_{u(x),v(x)}
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure on $U\times V$.

- Can we impose conditions on the moments of the measure $\mu$ such that $\Psi$ is this Dirac ?

Comment: You should add more details. This is a bit hard to follow.